# how to get session value to client-side without echo it out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use the session['something'] value inside my js, what if I don't print it out somewhere, how could I use that value?

only 2 ways I found
1) use hidden field trick
2) ajax

note : I've a 'huge' session data because it's an array

**update : I already have the session set in my index.php, and I want to use the array (the session) in my js file.**

Comment: "use hidden field trick" --- and how would you output it without `echo`? `ajax` --- how would you make an ajax response without `echo`?

Comment: @zerkms so ajax is not suite for my case

Comment: I'm guessing he don't want, or can't generate the JS on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it directly into JavaScript. A JSON "string" is perfectly parseable JavaScript, which is why one could `eval(jsonStr);` and get the same thing as `JSON.parse(jsonStr)` (although eval is discouraged for security reasons). If your nested `_SESSION` data is safe (e.g. sanitized already for JS), then there is nothing wrong with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var session = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>;
</script>
```

... then later on ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething(session);
}
</script>
```

You may wish to NOT dump the entire session to the client, in which case, just rebuild what you want (also showing an example of CDATA here since it is in a XHTML tree, if you're conscious of that):

```
<?php
$jsOut['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
$jsOut['public'] = $_SESSION['public'];
// omit $_SESSION['passhash']
$encodedJSON = json_encode($jsOut);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var session = <?php echo $encodedJSON; ?>;
//]]>
</script>
```

You can put a `<script>` tag right in the body/head of your HTML (i.e. as CDATA). It can be as simple as declaring an object in global or namespaced scope. Then just access that object (by whatever name you declared it with `var` as) within, by passing it into some "init" function which can be in any JS file included/loaded in the page (i.e. external or inline).

Remember, PHP is simply a preparser (hence the name) to whatever it is you want to generate. In this case, you're generating client-side code which can consist of HTML, CSS, even JS, or any other client-side tech (e.g. VBScript for IE). Heck, PHP can even dynamically write JavaScript if you wanted, which in its most simple form is what this solution is recommending.

Comment: I'm confused now, it's possible to write echo within js block? I mean your 1st block of code.. my session is in file index.php and I've separated js file.

Comment: @user3033162 updated answer, give it a read and see if it clicks, holler if you're still confused.

Comment: @user3033162 yeaa-ya! yw. Keep in mind: if you're storing any user-generated content in the _SESSION array and dumping it as JS, you *really need to* sanitize it first, just like you would for a MySQL insert, but only with JS in mind. If you don't, your users are vulnerable to either JS bugs or security exploits.

Comment: sanitize means? how can the user hijack my session?

Comment: @user3033162 I'm referring to things like http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/ but after reviewing json_encode, it seems like these aren't issues since the proper escaping and encapsulation is done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way a client can access any `$_SESSION` variable directly, so there are the only two options available if you cannot or do not want to echo the content of the variable in your JS.

Comment: so the best is echo a hidden array on index.php then use js to get the value?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need session data in the your presentation layer for continuous access, then you have two methods and you already have mentioned them.

1. Dump all the data in a JavaScript array and then use it.
2. Use AJAX and fetch it from your server.

If you are using a MVC framework, you can write a separate controller which gives you different methods for accessing the `SESSION` data. This way you will not expose the data all at once and can write orgazined code.